# 20.04 crashes with error \00\00\00

Tags: kernel, 20.04, crash, syslog

My freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 frequently crashes during normal activities. These are the last lines from `var/log/syslog` before the crash:

```
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.136396] RIP: 0010:kmem_cache_alloc_node+0x121/0x260
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.136397] Code: 75 0e 4d 89 f9 41 f6 47 0b 04 0f 84 4b ff ff ff 4c 89 ff e8 51 ff 01 00 49 89 c1 e9 3b ff ff ff 41 8b 41 20 49 8b 39 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 99 70 01 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.136398] RSP: 0018:ffffb5d598a4faf0 EFLAGS: 00010202
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.136399] RAX: 5c29693259fecd26 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.136399] RDX: 0000000001e7898b RSI: 0000000000000cc0 RDI: 0000000000031fc0
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.136400] RBP: ffffb5d598a4fb28 R08: ffff896ffe071fc0 R09: ffff896ff9c80700
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.136401] R10: 0000000000000033 R11: ffffb5d598a4fa50 R12: 5c29693259fecd26
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.136401] R13: 0000000000000cc0 R14: 00000000ffffffff R15: ffff896ff9c80700
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.136402] FS:  00007f84e30f3500(0000) GS:ffff896ffe040000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.136403] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.136403] CR2: 00007f84e2e8a100 CR3: 00000006ced84000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166419] general protection fault: 0000 [#44] SMP NOPTI
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166424] CPU: 1 PID: 1850071 Comm: php Tainted: P      D W  OE     5.4.0-39-generic #43-Ubuntu
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166425] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./X399 Taichi, BIOS P3.30 08/14/2018
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166430] RIP: 0010:kmem_cache_alloc_node+0x121/0x260
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166433] Code: 75 0e 4d 89 f9 41 f6 47 0b 04 0f 84 4b ff ff ff 4c 89 ff e8 51 ff 01 00 49 89 c1 e9 3b ff ff ff 41 8b 41 20 49 8b 39 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 99 70 01 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166434] RSP: 0018:ffffb5d5988bfd28 EFLAGS: 00010202
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166437] RAX: 5c29693259fecd26 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166438] RDX: 0000000001e7898b RSI: 0000000000000cc0 RDI: 0000000000031fc0
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166439] RBP: ffffb5d5988bfd60 R08: ffff896ffe071fc0 R09: ffff896ff9c80700
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166440] R10: ffff896facaa6040 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 5c29693259fecd26
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166441] R13: 0000000000000cc0 R14: 00000000ffffffff R15: ffff896ff9c80700
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166443] FS:  00007f98b6dd8700(0000) GS:ffff896ffe040000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166445] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166446] CR2: 00007f98bc80e9d0 CR3: 0000000ef8bfc000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166447] Call Trace:
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166453]  ? __alloc_skb+0x5a/0x1d0
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166455]  __alloc_skb+0x5a/0x1d0
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166458]  ? make_kuid+0x13/0x20
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166460]  sock_wmalloc+0x3a/0x60
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166463]  unix_stream_connect+0xc4/0x562
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166466]  ? __d_alloc+0x27/0x1f0
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166468]  ? __check_object_size+0x4d/0x150
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166471]  __sys_connect+0xf1/0x130
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166473]  ? __sys_socket+0x9e/0xf0
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166476]  __x64_sys_connect+0x1a/0x20
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166479]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166482]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166484] RIP: 0033:0x7f98bc7d51ab
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166486] Code: 83 ec 18 89 54 24 0c 48 89 34 24 89 7c 24 08 e8 cb 45 f7 ff 8b 54 24 0c 48 8b 34 24 41 89 c0 8b 7c 24 08 b8 2a 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 2f 44 89 c7 89 44 24 08 e8 01 46 f7 ff 8b 44
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166487] RSP: 002b:00007f98b6dd6fc0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002a
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166489] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000012 RCX: 00007f98bc7d51ab
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166490] RDX: 000000000000006e RSI: 00007f98b6dd7030 RDI: 0000000000000009
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166491] RBP: 00007f98b6dd70e0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007f98b6dd6fe0
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166492] R10: fffffffffffffdac R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000006
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166493] R13: 00007f98b6dd6fe0 R14: 00007f98bc86accb R15: 0000000000000009
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166495] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_MASQUERADE xt_state xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 iptable_filter xt_tcpudp bpfilter nf_nat_h323 nf_conntrack_h323 nf_nat_pptp nf_conntrack_pptp nf_nat_tftp nf_conntrack_tftp nf_nat_sip nf_conntrack_sip nf_nat_irc nf_conntrack_irc nf_nat_ftp nf_conntrack_ftp iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c ccm edac_mce_amd kvm_amd cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm nvidia_uvm(OE) nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek joydev input_leds aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_generic nvidia(POE) ledtrig_audio crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_seq_midi snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi iwlmvm btusb wmi_bmof btrtl snd_hda_core mac80211 mxm_wmi snd_hwdep libarc4 btbcm btintel snd_seq bluetooth snd_pcm iwlwifi snd_seq_device ecdh_generic snd_timer ecc k10temp drm_kms_helper cfg80211 ipmi_devintf snd
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166531]  ipmi_msghandler soundcore fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid ses enclosure scsi_transport_sas uas usb_storage crc32_pclmul nvme igb i2c_piix4 nvme_core ahci i2c_algo_bit dca libahci gpio_amdpt wmi gpio_generic
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166551] ---[ end trace f61575867cc96eaa ]---
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166553] RIP: 0010:kmem_cache_alloc_node+0x121/0x260
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166555] Code: 75 0e 4d 89 f9 41 f6 47 0b 04 0f 84 4b ff ff ff 4c 89 ff e8 51 ff 01 00 49 89 c1 e9 3b ff ff ff 41 8b 41 20 49 8b 39 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 99 70 01 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166556] RSP: 0018:ffffb5d598a4faf0 EFLAGS: 00010202
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166558] RAX: 5c29693259fecd26 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166559] RDX: 0000000001e7898b RSI: 0000000000000cc0 RDI: 0000000000031fc0
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166560] RBP: ffffb5d598a4fb28 R08: ffff896ffe071fc0 R09: ffff896ff9c80700
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166561] R10: 0000000000000033 R11: ffffb5d598a4fa50 R12: 5c29693259fecd26
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166562] R13: 0000000000000cc0 R14: 00000000ffffffff R15: ffff896ff9c80700
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166564] FS:  00007f98b6dd8700(0000) GS:ffff896ffe040000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166565] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul  2 01:23:16 ubuntu1 kernel: [363076.166566] CR2: 00007f98bc80e9d0 CR3: 0000000ef8bfc000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
```

**free -h**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           94Gi       9.2Gi        39Gi       177Mi        45Gi        84Gi
Swap:         127Gi          0B       127Gi
```

**vm.swappiness = 60**

```
sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: P3.90
       date: 12/04/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 8
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 64GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a) [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 0
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: CMK32GX4M2D3000C16
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a) [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 0
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: CMK32GX4M2D3000C16
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:4
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a) [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 4
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 0
     *-bank:5
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: CMK32GX4M2D3000C16
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 5
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:6
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a) [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 6
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 0
     *-bank:7
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: CMK32GX4M2D3000C16
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 7
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: b
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 1536KiB
       capacity: 1536KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: c
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: d
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 32MiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. The \00\00\00 in the log is just a side effect of the crash. Is there any more available in the log, as I think you're missing the beginning of the crash detail.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for your kind attention. I included further information as you instructed, and added more log lines. Other unusual behaviour in my log in this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255634/wpa-supplicant-ctrl-event-scan-failed-error but it was not the case in the latest crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Memory**

Your memory may not be installed correctly.

In a <strike>dual-channel</strike> (quad-channel) memory controller configuration, matched pairs of RAM DIMMs are installed into <strike>channel A and channel B</strike> (channels A/B/C/D). The naming convention varies between vendors.

Your banks 0/1/2/3 are correct, in that DIMMs are installed into DIMM0 and DIMM1 pair slots.

Your banks 4/5/6/7 are incorrect, in that DIMMs are in DIMM1 slots. You should move bank 7 DIMM to bank 4 DIMM slot, so that `sudo lshw -C memory` shows banks 4/5 occupied as DIMM0 and DIMM1, and banks 6/7 as empty.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**BIOS**

ASRock X399 Taichi

You have BIOS P3.30 08/14/2018

There's a newer BIOS available. 3.90 dated 1/8/2020, and can be downloaded from [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/X399%20Taichi/index.asp#BIOS)

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**swap**

Your /swapfile or swap partition is excessive at 127G. We'll have to discuss appropriate sizing.

**Update #1:**

You should be adding RAM in groups of 2, or 4, or 8 DIMMs. You have 6 DIMMs. You may have to use 4 DIMMs to configure as per the below chart, and keep 2 DIMMs out.

Use `sudo lshw -C memory` to determine if DIMMs are in the correct slots, so that equal numbers of DIMM0 and DIMM1 are populated.

Here are images from the User Manual...

[image]
[image]

Comment: I checked the motherboard manual (https://download.asrock.com/Manual/X399%20Taichi.pdf) again. I think I have installed the memories correctly (banks 5 and 7 should be populated first).

Comment: @Googlebot  Pages 7, 8, and 20 indicate letter numbers, rather than bank numbers, as I indicated might happen based on vendor design. If you look at `sudo lshw -C memory` you'll see that each memory pair, starting with bank 0 and 1, are showing as DIMM0 and DIMM1. Same for banks 2 and 3. But banks 4-7 show both DIMMS as DIMM1. That's wrong.

Comment: @Googlebot To maybe prove it either way, run `memtest`, as described in my answer.

Comment: I trust your point, as you are absolutely right about DIMM. I just meant the position of slots as mapped in the manual. I installed the first four according to the map on page 20 and added the additional two. I have populated slots DDR4_C2 and DDR4_D2 as DDR4_C1 and DDR4_D1 are free.

Comment: @Googlebot Yes, the manual would have you believe that you should be adding memory in either groups of 2, or 4, or 8... and you have 6 DIMMs. I don't know if yours are labelled the same on the motherboard, as in the manual. But I'd move that one DIMM until `lshw` shows banks 4/5 occupied as DIMM0 and DIMM1, and banks 6/7 as empty. It IS confusing though :-)

Comment: @Googlebot Status please...

Comment: @Googlebot Status please...

Comment: sorry for my tardy action. I look for a chance to run the test, as I am in the middle of a project.

Comment: sorry for my late reply. I followed your advice. I updated the BIOS. I changed the RAM slots, and it is now banks 0-5 are populated (after trial and error, I found out that the banks are exactly the order of slots from right to left. Now, on the left side, slots C1 and C2; it is against what instructed in the manual). When I run Memtest86+ from the Ubuntu boot menu, it freezes after 10% pass, `Test 1 [Address test, own address, Sequential]`. I will keep experimenting and keep you posted.

Comment: @Googlebot Please see Update #1 in my answer. It'll help you populate the DIMMs on the motherboard. Use `sudo lshw -C memory` to determine if they're installed correctly with an equal number in DIMM0 slots, and DIMM1 slots. If `memtest` freezes, you either have some bad RAM, or it isn't configured correctly. Report back.

Comment: thanks for your kind attention. I updated the `sudo lshw -C memory` to reflect the current configuration. I understand that 6 RAMs are not common (I intend to add two more in the first possible time). However, the system works well, and I am still not sure if the crash is because of memory failure. The RAMs are relatively new (2-3 months old). `memtest` freezes right after starting. Using multi-thread (by `F2`), it went until 10% pass and then froze.

Comment: Wow best looking answer I've seen in a long time.

Comment: @Googlebot Install only 4 DIMMs, into the configuration marked **Priority 2** in the above images, and rerun `memtest` and let's see if that works. Report back.

Comment: @Googlebot And once we get `memtest` sorted out, we have to fix your swap configuration.

Comment: @Googlebot Status please...

Comment: my job is data analysis. When I start an analysis, I cannot turn off my computer for a few days until it is finished.

Comment: `memtest` freezes for 4-RAM configuration too. I updated `sudo lshw -C memory` for 4-RAM configuration. As I said in the beginning, the RAM installation was correct as I had followed the manual.

Comment: In any case, I believe the problem is not the memory. I swapped two GPUs to use the other one for display, and I have not experienced any crash so far. Hence, I think the problem was my GPU.

Comment: @Googlebot In the 4 DIMM configuration, you have DIMMs in slots A2/B2 and C2/D2, yes? Memtest should run no matter what GPU you have installed. Until memtest run, not freezes, I still think there's a problem. Do you have a Ryzen processor? Ryzens are notorious for memory problems. Try the 2 DIMM configuration and retry memtest. If it freezes again, remove the 2 DIMMs and try 2 other DIMMs.

Comment: Yes, all four are installed in `2` slots. Surely, `memtest` is independent of GPU. I meant the crash (the main question) has not occurred since I swapped the GPUs. Evidently, the memory performance is not optimised, but the system smoothly works. The `memtest` failure should be related to the Ryzen issue you mentioned. I will keep experimenting.

Comment: @Googlebot Yes, try the **Priority 1** memory config with only 2 DIMMs and see if `memtest` runs ok. If it runs, cycle the other two DIMMs via the same slots. If they all run `memtest` in this config, but not when all 4 DIMMs are installed, it's a Ryzen memory compatibility problem, as I referred to earlier. I had one like this just last week. It took a long time to figure it out. We ended up swapping DIMMs with new ones that were on their compatible memory list.