# wpa_supplicant CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED error

Tags: networking, network-manager, iwlwifi, wpa-supplicant

I have two WiFi cards, as I use one as a hotspot. My `/var/log/syslog` is filled with `wpa_supplicant` errors:

```
Jul  2 07:50:44 ubuntu1 wpa_supplicant[1347]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1
Jul  2 07:55:00 ubuntu1 wpa_supplicant[1347]: message repeated 256 times: [ wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1]
Jul  2 07:55:01 ubuntu1 CRON[2708510]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul  2 07:55:01 ubuntu1 wpa_supplicant[1347]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1
```

My cards are

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 03
       serial: 70:85:c2:ae:42:71
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=0. 4-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:36 memory:d9500000-d951ffff ioport:2000(size=32) memory:d9520000-d9523fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 10
       serial: 18:56:80:92:f3:2e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-40-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 ip=10.42.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:95 memory:d9400000-d9401fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 03
       serial: 70:85:c2:ae:42:6f
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=0. 4-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:34 memory:d9300000-d931ffff ioport:1000(size=32) memory:d9320000-d9323fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 5c:80:b6:fd:b4:7f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-40-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=192.168.0.182 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:42 memory:d9200000-d9203fff
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar issue. One WLAN card, one Ethernet. WLAN is set up to automatically create a hotspot when I start my computer and keep it on at all times. I had no connectivity issues at all, but my log file was absolutely filled with:

```
CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1
```

with a new log entry every single second (for months).

Adding:

```
[device]
match-device=driver:<YOUR-DEVICE-NAME>
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` seems to have solved it.

`<YOUR-DEVICE-NAME>` in my case was gathered from running `ifconfig` in a terminal and locating my WLAN card, which was `wlp4s0` in my case.

Comment: Note that the `match-device` line may be omitted, in which case mac address randomization will be disabled unconditionally. Might be useful for example for testing that this works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You don't happen to have turned the WiFi off by accident (e.g via some function key)? There have been some regression chats in the past time concerning this [problem](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235916)

I'd try to create a file as
`/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/intel_sp.conf` with following content:

```
[device]
match-device=driver:iwlwifi
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Reboot and try. Each driver is different, but this might help

Answer (score 0):

[frogpeople's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1294366/618353) did not work for me. Finally I found that adding the following section to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` works well:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Comment: This will set NetworkManager to ignore your wireless interface, different behavior